# CC.NET + SVN : Server certificate issue

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, svn, cruisecontrol

I am trying to setup Continuous Integration in our office. Being a puny little developer I am facing this supposedly infamous problem:
" Source control operation failed: svn: OPTIONS of 'https://trunkURL': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted"

So I tried the following solution
- Run CC.NET service (server running as win service) using a domain account (rather than default LOCAL SYSTEMS) and accept cert permanently using command prompt under that user by using svn log/list on the repo.

Doesn't help :(. I am getting the following from my artifact/log files(or dashboard)

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: OPTIONS of 'https://TrunkURL': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://ServerAdd)
. Process command: E:\(svn.exe Path) log https://TrunkURL -r "{2010-11-08T02:12:20Z}:{2010-11-08T02:13:21Z}" --verbose --xml --no-auth-cache --non-interactive
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModificationsWithLogging(ISourceControl sc, IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

We are using VisualSVN Server and CC.NET for this adventure. Tips, suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: anyone? with some answer? still waiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy solution ... see "3. Accept SSL exception for CruiseControl.Net local user account." in this link

http://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/configuring-cruisecontrol-net-svn-visual-studio-2008-and-msbuild/

Answer (score -2):

Starting the cmd.exe as "SYSTEM" account and using any SVN command didn't work for me. At the first time, I was prompted to accept the certificate, did so (permanently) and hoped that CC.NET was cured by this. It wasn't.

Finally, I went to my "normal" user's %APPDATA%\Subversion and copied some files (mainly auth/svn.ssl.server) over to the %APPDATA%\Subversion-folder of the "LocalService" and "NetworkService" users. That did the trick for me.